# BeautifulSoup error Python 3.4.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Python 3.4.3 (64 bit) Windows 7
My bs4/requests were running fine then I got all this stuff from my program bs1.py:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2218, in _find_and_load_unlocked
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\myprograms\bs1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests, bs4
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\utils.py", line 12, in <module>
    import cgi
  File "C:\Python34\lib\cgi.py", line 42, in <module>
    import html
  File "C:\Python34\myprograms\html.py", line 11, in <module>
    import bs4
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .builder import builder_registry
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from bs4.element import (
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 5, in <module>
    from bs4.dammit import EntitySubstitution
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\bs4\dammit.py", line 11, in <module>
    from html.entities import codepoint2name
ImportError: No module named 'html.entities'; 'html' is not a package
```

If I enter each program line to Python Shell it works fine and finds bs4 etc
I reloaded Python 3.4 and reinstalled BeautifulSoup and requests and reloaded the bs4 file from the .zip file
but no change. It is as if the Run executes from another library. I get the same if I run from the CMD line.
Code:

```
import requests, bs4
url="http://www.utexas.edu/world/univ/alpha/"
page = requests.get(url)
page.raise_for_status()
#soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup((page.text), "html.parser")
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup((page.text),)
print("soup.title ", soup.title)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a local file named `html.py` that masks the standard library package named `html`.

Rename the file, or delete it altogether. If you have trouble locating it, import it to print the filename:

```
import html; print(html.__file__)
```

Once out of the way, the `html.entities` import will succeed again.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, it's always the obvious that's the answer